# map inside another map in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have this json format of notes :

```
{
  "document_tone": {
    "tone_categories": [
      {
        "tones": [
          {
            "score": 0.027962,
            "tone_id": "anger",
            "tone_name": "Colère"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.114214,
            "tone_id": "sadness",
            "tone_name": "Tristesse"
          }
        ],
        "category_id": "emotion_tone",
        "category_name": "Ton émotionnel"
      },
      {
        "tones": [
          {
            "score": 0.028517,
            "tone_id": "analytical",
            "tone_name": "Analytique"
          },
          {
            "score": 0,
            "tone_id": "tentative",
            "tone_name": "Hésitant"
          }
        ],
        "category_id": "language_tone",
        "category_name": "Ton de langage"
      },
      {
        "tones": [
          {
            "score": 0.289319,
            "tone_id": "openness_big5",
            "tone_name": "Ouverture"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.410613,
            "tone_id": "conscientiousness_big5",
            "tone_name": "Tempérament consciencieux"
          },
          {
            "score": 0.956493,
            "tone_id": "emotional_range_big5",
            "tone_name": "Portée émotionnelle"
          }
        ],
        "category_id": "social_tone",
        "category_name": "Ton social"
      }
    ]
  },
  "idMedia": 25840
}
```

I am trying to map the array of objects of `tone_categories` and after that map the array of objects of tones to get to the `category_name`

I have done this :

```
notes !== undefined && notes !== "" &&  notes.length !== 0 ?
notes.document_tone.tone_categories.map((item, idx) => {
  notes.document_tone.tone_categories[item].tones.map((item2, idx2) => {
    {console.log('notesssss',notes.document_tone.tone_categories[item].tones[item2].category_name)}
  })
}) :
 null}
```

I am getting this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tones' of undefined
```

Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong any help wouls be appreciated Thank you

Comment: You forgot to return inside `.map`

Comment: You're attempting to reference 'tones' from notes.document_tone.tone_categories[item]. Try passing 'idx' (the index) instead of 'item' (the object). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `category_name` it should be:

```
const results = notes.document_tone.tone_categories.map(item => {
  return item.category_name
});
```

([working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-euclid-3syli))